# What do "appearance" and "shape" mean in computer vision?

Tags: computer-vision, computer-science

In computer vision tasks like object class recognition, often terms like "appearance" and "shape" are mentioned. What do they mean?
For example, in this paper [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/fergus03.pdf), they do recognition using information of appearance and shape.

In my opinion, the appearance of a patch/image means how does the path/image look like. Normally we use some descriptor (e.g. SIFT) to describe the appearance. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Think of an image of an single object e.g. a football.

Shape is the geometry of the given object, which can be described with the help vector or edge points - thus, it might also include its location. Here it would be a simple sphere. This can also depend on the perspective of the viewer.

The appearance would incorporate the texture and color of the object.